# latex files generated by tikzdevice leaves large space between image and caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, plot, tikzdevice

Ive been using the tikzdevice package in R to generate latex code of my plots, I've noticed that it always leaves a large white space between the caption and the figure itself, here is an example I generated:

first, this is how I am including it in my file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[active,tightpage,psfixbb]{preview}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\include{example}
\caption{apples}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and here is the file that \include{example} (output from tikzdevice) refers to:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt,scale=0.5]
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\path[use as bounding box,fill=fillColor,fill opacity=0.00] (0,0) rectangle (505.89,505.89);
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] ( 49.20, 61.20) rectangle (480.69,456.69);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 65.18, 75.85) --
    (109.57, 86.94) --
    (153.97,105.44) --
    (198.36,131.33) --
    (242.75,164.62) --
    (287.14,205.31) --
    (331.53,253.40) --
    (375.92,308.88) --
    (420.32,371.76) --
    (464.71,442.04);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (505.89,505.89);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (109.57, 61.20) -- (464.71, 61.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (109.57, 61.20) -- (109.57, 55.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (198.36, 61.20) -- (198.36, 55.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (287.14, 61.20) -- (287.14, 55.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (375.92, 61.20) -- (375.92, 55.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (464.71, 61.20) -- (464.71, 55.20);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (109.57, 39.60) {2};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (198.36, 39.60) {4};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (287.14, 39.60) {6};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (375.92, 39.60) {8};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (464.71, 39.60) {10};

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20, 72.15) -- ( 49.20,442.04);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20, 72.15) -- ( 43.20, 72.15);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,146.13) -- ( 43.20,146.13);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,220.11) -- ( 43.20,220.11);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,294.08) -- ( 43.20,294.08);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,368.06) -- ( 43.20,368.06);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,442.04) -- ( 43.20,442.04);

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80, 72.15) {0};

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80,146.13) {20};

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80,220.11) {40};

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80,294.08) {60};

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80,368.06) {80};

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80,442.04) {100};

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20, 61.20) --
    (480.69, 61.20) --
    (480.69,456.69) --
    ( 49.20,456.69) --
    ( 49.20, 61.20);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (505.89,505.89);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (264.94, 15.60) {x};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

does anyone know how to get rid of this excessive space? I've tried using the caption package but that doesn't seem to work for files generated by tikzdevice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main source of blank space is the use of `\include` instead of `\input`. Compare:

[image: Comparison]

If you consider the spacing still too large, you can edit your `example.tex` (tikzdevice output). It begins with:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt,scale=0.5]
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\path[use as bounding box,fill=fillColor,fill opacity=0.00] (0,0) rectangle (505.89,505.89);
```

This initial rectangle is what defines the bounding box of the whole figure, which is the size reserved for it. If you "cheat" and use a smaller bounding box, the caption will be closer. For example, to raise the caption 6ex, you have to define a bounding box which is 6ex shorter at the bottom, which is easy:

```
\path[use as bounding box,fill=fillColor,fill opacity=0.00] (0,6ex) rectangle (505.89,505.89);
```

The result in this case:

[image: Result]

Comment: I am using \input and still have this problem. I can use (cheat) the bounding box, but doing it for more than 20-30 figures is not easy task.